# handling listener on toolbar onOptionsItemSelected - android

Tags: android, listener, toolbar

My toolbar has a radiogroup(with 2 radiobuttons) and a button. I can easily handle button clicks by using `item.getItemId() == R.id.button` on `onOptionsItemSelected` method but when I use it on my radiogroup it never runs. (ex: `item.getItemId() == R.id.mySwitch`), I'm guessing its a radiogroup and not a selectable object.

But the main question is I have a listener for my radiogroup, which is in `onOptionsItemSelected` method. The listener doesn't work at the start of the app, I have to activate `onOptionsItemSelected`, then the listener works. I use my button which is beside the radiogroup to activate `onOptionsItemSelected`, after that everything works fine.

Is there a way to call `onOptionsItemSelected` onCreate method or make my listener activate without using a dummy button to activate it?

Note: These objects are on my toolbar

**Main Activity**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.mySwitch);
    item.setActionView(R.layout.customtoggle);
    item.setCheckable(true);
    return true;
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
if (item.getItemId() == R.id.button) {
   System.out.println("Button pressed!");

}

//The code below never gets runned 
if (item.getItemId() == R.id.mySwitch) {
    System.out.println("WORKS");
}


RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.toggle);
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        // find which radio button is selected
        if (checkedId == R.id.rbtn1) {
            System.out.println("Radio btn 1 pressed");

        } else if (checkedId == R.id.rbtn2) {
            System.out.println("Radio btn2 pressed");


        }
    }

});


return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**Menu__main.xml**

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/mySwitch"
        android:title="switch"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/customtoggle"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

> Oncreate

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.toggle);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // find which radio button is selected
            if (checkedId == R.id.rbtn1) {
                System.out.println("Radio btn 1 pressed");

            } else if (checkedId == R.id.rbtn2) {
                System.out.println("Radio btn2 pressed");


            }
        }

    });

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        System.out.println("ONCREATE");

    }
```

Comment: Move the `RadioGroup` stuff to `onCreate()`, after the `setContentView()` call.

Comment: I cant to that because my main activity setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); and not R.menu.menu_main,  I tried it before and got null pointer exception, something like refering to null object, Remember these items are in toolbar, if im not mistaken they have to be handled in onopitionmenu

Comment: You are mistaken. It doesn't matter if they're in your `Toolbar`, they're not going to fire the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method. If you're getting an NPE when you set the listener in `onCreate()`, then that's a different problem. Make sure you're calling `findViewById()` after the `setContentView()` call.

Comment: Ok, could you show an example code of how to do this? It would be much help

Comment: Post your `onCreate()` method and the stack trace, and we can tell you what's wrong.

Comment: I did what you said, and got this error: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{path.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.RadioGroup$OnCheckedChangeListener)' on a null object reference` I will update my question with the oncreate code. Not sure what you mean with stack trace through

Comment: Are your `RadioButton`s in the `customtoggle` layout?

Comment: tried clean build and rebuild, still same error, the codes works fine on `onOptionsItemSelected`, yes my buttons are in customtoggle.xml (layout)

Comment: Is it more tricky to use the listener on oncreate because I  have a own layout for radiobutton? I am using a custom design for radio button so i have to have a layout, Btw it was  `item.setActionView(R.layout.customtoggle);` not (R.layout.toggle) as I previously had on my `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` method

Comment: OK, so they are in that custom layout. When you said "in the toolbar", I assumed they were actually in the `Toolbar` `View`. The problem is that your menu items aren't going to inflate until well after `onCreate()` is done. You're not actually using the `RadioGroup` as a menu item, so you could just put them in the `Toolbar` directly, and your current code would work. If you want to keep them as a menu item for some reason, you need to move the `RadioGroup` stuff to `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, and call `findViewById()` on `item.getActionView()`, after the `setActionView()` call.